# Probability of number of missing balls

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a collection of $n(>3)$ distinct balls indexed $1,2...n$ .
I pick $3$, balls at random and and note the index. I replace the balls drawn. I do this experiment for a total of $n$ times. Then I look at all the indices that I noted . If $Y_{n}$ denotes the number of indices out of $1,2,..n$ that are missing. Then what is $\mathbb{E}({Y_{n}}).$ ?

Here is what I have tried.

Let $X_{i}$ be the Random Variable such that $X_{i}=1$ if the ith ball never shows up. And $X_{i}=0$ if ith ball shows up.

Then the number of missing balls is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ .  We have $P(X_{i}=1)=\left(\frac{\binom{n-1}{3}}{\binom{n}{3}}\right)^{n}$ .
So $$\mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}(X_{i})=n\left(\frac{\binom{n-1}{3}}{\binom{n}{3}}\right)^{n}$$ . But here I have a problem.

Mainly because $Y_{n}\leq n-3$ . As atleast $3$ distinct balls is guaranteed by the first picking.

So If I have to take that into account.

Then if I try to directly compute $\mathbb{E}({Y_{n}})$. Then $P(Y_{n}=i)=\binom{n}{i}\left(\frac{\binom{n-i}{3}}{\binom{n}{3}}\right)^{n}$

Then I get the expectation as $$\sum_{i=1}^{n-2} i\binom{n}{i}\left(\frac{\binom{n-i}{3}}{\binom{n}{3}}\right)^{n}$$.

The probability is like that because I choose the i balls which will be missing first and then I compute the probability that those $i$ balls never show up.

But I do not know how to compute this summation.

Any suggestions as to how to solve this problem is appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is with the first solution. $n\left(\frac{\binom{n-1}{3}}{\binom{n}{3}}\right)^{n}=(n-3)\left(\frac{n-3}{n}\right)^{n-1}$ which satisfy the requirement that $Y_{n}\leq n-3$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja I am also not sure . First I computed in the first way yesterday. Then in the morning I thought that wait.....$\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ can take value $1,2...n$. But that would not be consistent with the experiment. However the way you rearranged the terms, it might somehow justifies it.  Can you explain it in words once. I think that would clarify where I am having the misconception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any particular number.

P(not in the first pick of $3) = 1 - \dfrac 3 n = \dfrac{n-3}n$

P(not in any of the $n$ picks of $3) = \left(\dfrac {n-3}  {n}\right)^n$

Then  expected numbers missing $= n\left(\dfrac {n-3}  {n}\right)^n$

Comment: This is just the same as how I did it. $\left(\frac{\binom{n-1}{3}}{\binom{n}{3}}\right)=\frac{n-3}{n}$ . Can you please explain where and why the first and the 2nd methods are different and how do I justify that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ can take values $1,2,...n$ but $Y_{n}$ takes values in $1,2,...n-3$

Comment: Okay I sort of get it but it is still not clear. Also can you provide some insight into how to compute the summation for $Y_{n}$ or was the thinking and the expression for $Y_{n}$ was at all correct?

Comment: It got confusing because there are $n$ balls and $n$ picks of $3$. Consider a case of, say,  $30$ balls and $10$ picks of $3,$ and work out.